Why does moving these two curve vertices give such different results?
Does anyone know what key combination or function can help me control hair 1 to be likehair 2 without it spinning around like in the gif?
(More specifically: Which key combination should I press so that when moving a vertex ofhair 1 it matches withhair 2, not as in the gif)
Mind map:hair 1 -> (key combination?) -> Ctrl + T (to adjust the angle to match the original) ->hair 2 (can move the vertex like hair 2 without affecting other vertices like hair 1)


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

One curve has a different direction. Hence, you are manipulating the start of hair 1 and the end of hair 2.
Select either curve in edit mode and choose W > Switch Direction.
